# ActiveX control in C++ form based application

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, activex

Is it possible to use ActiveX control in C++ form based application like we use in MFC dialog based applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can host an ActiveX control in WinForms using the [AxHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.axhost.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks! Can you plz provide some sample examples for its use. Is it possible to use the ActiveX control like any other tool in the toolbox?